# What is the mysterious box?

Tags: kingdom-two-crowns

[image: screenshot of box...]
In kingdom two crowns there is a mysterious box that appeared a while ago that costs 1 diamond... what does it do? Should I buy it? I looked for what it could be but I have no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chest is [Stone Coffer](https://kingdomthegame.fandom.com/wiki/Gems#Stone_Coffer). After you upgraded to Stone Castle, it will appear. Every gem stored there will be avaliable between islands if you pay 1 gold to the NPC next to it per gem.